# How to bypass authentication in selenium

Tags: authentication, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to automate a secure application(with useragent - iphone) which asks for authentication when i open the site. I tried giving the credentials in the URL itself to bypass the authentication but it pops up a dialogbox for confirmation which i'm unable to handle it through code.

```java
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();     
profile.setPreference("general.useragent.override",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420.1"
    + "(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/3B48b Safari/419.3)"); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile); 
String site = "http://akamai:ecnt0k3n@ecn13-secure-store.nike.com";
driver.get(site);
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bhavana

Comment: By authentication are you saying "proxy authentication"

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla blocks fishing attempts. Did you check [Network.http.phishy-userpass-length](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.phishy-userpass-length)?

By the way, according to [Selenium's issue 34#8](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=34#c8), this should work:

```java
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.get("http://username:password@www.basicauthprotected.com/");
```

Note: this question is almost the same as [BASIC Authentication in Selenium 2 - set up for FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver and IEdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5672407/413020).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium's new WebDriver to enter information into a dialog box of that type. However I haven't done it.