# Opening a password protected page in Python and Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to open this local IP in my web browser.

```
   from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    url = 'http://165.269.261.210/source/'
    page = urllib.urlopen(url)
```

when I run the above code it asks for username and password on Python shell.

```
Enter username for coffee at 165.269.261.210: agrawal

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\getpass.py", line 92
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Enter password for agrawal.a in coffee at 165.269.261.210: bravokid
```

after I provide username and password nothing opens in Firefox ?
and also how can I provide username and password in the code itself ?
Is there any better way to do it?

Update: 
When I directly put the link in the browser a pop-up opens asking for username and password. Only after I provide the username & password page opens otherwise throws 401 error

Comment: so username and password is asked on the python shell... not on the firefox window?

Comment: yes,and it is asked before the page opens. and if not provided it throws 401 error

Comment: can you edit the question little more in detail? How the user name and password are effecting opening of the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://165.269.261.210/source/'

# This is no way connected to Selenium, but fetches URL using Python urllib library
# page = urllib.urlopen(url)
driver.get('http://username:password@165.269.261.210/source/')
```

Instead, use `driver.get()` method as [explained in the Selenium WebDriver tutorial](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html).

[Further, you need to pass username and password in the URL for HTTP Basic Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9262587/315168).

Comment: Yes I think this is the right way. but in my case it is giving error
IOError: [Errno http error] no host given