# How to override basic authentication in selenium2 with Java using chrome driver?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to override basic authentication in selenium2 chrome driver?
I am facing an issue in my project where chrome "Authentication required" popup is coming which is blocking webdriver to continue navigation.
Please find the attached screenshot for the same.
[image]
I am using following code to instantiate chrome driver,

```
private WebDriver driver;
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Selenium/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.tearDown();
}
```

Could you please help -

Thanks,

Comment: Please see [BASIC Authentication in Selenium 2 - set up for FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver and IEdriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5672407/1245497)

Comment: this is tell abt HTMLUnit framework and i tried to implement the same in my project. but code didnt work out, why b'se its not Selenium webdriver code. pls help with selenium webdriver code. thanks-

Answer (score 8):

I've struggled with the same problem over an hour and finally @kenorb's solution rescued me. To be short you need to add a browser extension that does the authentication for you (since Selenium itself can't do that!).

Here is how it works for **Chrome** and **Python**:

1. Create a zip file **proxy.zip** containing two files:

**background.js**

```
var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
      singleProxy: {
        scheme: "http",
        host: "YOU_PROXY_ADDRESS",
        port: parseInt(YOUR_PROXY_PORT)
      },
      bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
    }
  };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "YOUR_PROXY_USERNAME",
            password: "YOUR_PROXY_PASSWORD"
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
        callbackFn,
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ['blocking']
);
```

Don't forget to replace **YOUR_PROXY_*** to your settings.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
```

2. Add the created proxy.zip as an extension

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

   chrome_options = Options()
   chrome_options.add_extension("proxy.zip")

   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
   driver.get("http://google.com")
   driver.close()
   ```

That's it. For me that worked like a charm. If you need to create proxy.zip dynamically or need PHP example then go to the [original post](https://github.com/RobinDev/Selenium-Chrome-HTTP-Private-Proxy)

Comment: What about Java? How can I do that using java?

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried to get your example working, but it failed. Would you mind having a look at my question? I have an example on Github https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458165/err-tunnel-connection-failed-using-proxy-api-extension-with-selenium

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, but someone posted an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458165/create-http-basic-auth-chrome-extension-for-selenium-mwe-available that did

Comment: Mike, I failed with this log: http://joxi.net/LmG3OVNTRbEMam The last lines are : `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot process extension #1
from unknown error: cannot read manifest
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)` Any advice?

Comment: Ty soooo much! i was about to give up on this. Am using it with RobotFramework :
```python
Set Proxy Extension
    ${chrome_options} =     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    # Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    --incognito
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_extension    proxy.zip
    [return]    ${chrome_options}

${chrome_options}=    Set Proxy Extension
Create Webdriver      Chrome        chrome_options=${chrome_options}
```
Does not work on incognito, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17443982/665823

Answer (score 4):

I think you're talking about using **NTLM Authentication** (*windows integrated authentication*) not **Basic Authentication** (*where you provider your credentials in URL*). Assuming that here is what you can try for running NTML auth in chrome:

### Approach 1

Go to Internet Explorer, and open "Internet Options". Follow following steps:

- Add your site to either Local intranet or Trusted sites [image: add]
- [image: List item]
- [image: List item]
- [image: List item]
- [image: List item]

After these changes, your chrome authentication should work. If you're wondering that how IE settings effect chrome behavior then, Chrome uses IE security settings for authentication.

Some good resources / credits:

1. [Good details](https://sysadminspot.com/windows/google-chrome-and-ntlm-auto-logon-using-windows-authentication/)
2. [Selenium issue details](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=34)

### Approach 2

Add your site to **Local intranet** and don't change anything for user authentication. By default, second option (*Automatic logon only in Intranet sites*) is selected.

Comment: The question is about the google chrome. But you have provided the answer related to IE.

Comment: Yes, because when I answered this question, Chrome used to pull the security information from IE. Didn't check if it's valid today.

Comment: Approach 1 worked well with Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit), didn't try Approach 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding the login credentials to the url get request (in Java):

```
driver.get("http://username:password@google.com/")
```

Comment: Basic authentication doesn't have very good support in Selenium, as you've found. There is a feature request at the project page, and there are several comments and workarounds listed. You might want to check it out [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=34#c32)

Comment: Works for me with Selenium WebDriver

Comment: I have written my code as above. But unfortunately, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do that sending the credentials twice. I don't know why, but in the second time the browser sends the packet, the authentication header goes with basic authentication.

My code (using C#):

```
string url = "http://user:password@google.com/";
IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
webDriver.Url = url;
```

Comment: This is Nonsense

Answer (score -1):

Apart of configuring [Network Proxy Preferences](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#chrome), you can set `http_proxy` in `/etc/environment`.

Other method is to use [Chrome HTTP Private Proxy](https://github.com/RobinDev/Selenium-Chrome-HTTP-Private-Proxy) (which is based on [Chrome-proxy-helper](https://github.com/henices/Chrome-proxy-helper)).

Here is PHP example (found in README):

```
$pluginForProxyLogin = '/tmp/a'.uniqid().'.zip';

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$res = $zip->open($pluginForProxyLogin, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
$zip->addFile('/path/to/Chrome-proxy-helper/manifest.json', 'manifest.json');
$background = file_get_contents('/path/to/Chrome-proxy-helper/background.js');
$background = str_replace(['%proxy_host', '%proxy_port', '%username', '%password'], ['5.39.64.181', '54991', 'd1g1m00d', '13de02d0e0z9'], $background);
$zip->addFromString('background.js', $background);
$zip->close();

putenv("webdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver");

$options = new ChromeOptions();
$options->addExtensions([$pluginForProxyLogin]);
$caps = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$caps->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);

$driver = ChromeDriver::start($caps);
$driver->get('https://old-linux.com/ip/');

header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $driver->takeScreenshot();


unlink($pluginForProxyLogin);
```

The same logic should work for other languages as well.

More portable solution is reported already on [SeleniumHQ GitHub](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/453).

See also:

- [How to perform Basic Authentication for FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver and IEdriver in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672407/how-to-perform-basic-authentication-for-firefoxdriver-chromedriver-and-iedriver)
- [How to send Basic Authentication headers in Selenium?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/12892/2840) at SQA SE