# How to log in to localsite using chrome login dialog box with selenium and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to log to a local site using chrome using selenium and python. I've tried using:

```
driver.get('user.name:!#$EDCzzzzzzzz@http://localhost/');
```

but whenever I do that I get warning that my url is in **invalid format**. I suppose it has to do with the way that passoword is (has !@#$ in it etc.) I cannot change that password. Any ideas? Is there a way to target chrome dialog popup with xpath? What should I look for as a solution.

Comment: you can try with the format http: //username:pwd@localhost/

Comment: Still same error, "Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (-),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)"

Comment: Instead of localhost, you try with your machine ip address

Comment: still same error, I think it has to do with password having other symbols than  just letters, or maybe that username is divided with dot

Comment: I tried your code locally under python 2 and python 3, it works just fine 

`from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('user.name:!#$EDCzzzzzzzz@http://localhost/');
`
You could be right that the problem is related to the special characters. Try encoding your url, or just parts of it (username + password + @(?)).

Here's the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.1) for url, directly to user information.

Comment: If you are using the latest version of chromedriver, then this format is not supported. [check this](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/34#c32)

Comment: These might help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672407/how-to-perform-basic-authentication-for-firefoxdriver-chromedriver-and-iedriver) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888323/how-to-override-basic-authentication-in-selenium2-with-java-using-chrome-driver). Also, these are not for Python.

Comment: I've managed to fix my issue by converting manually password to urlencoded text