# selenium-webdriver chrome proxy authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to setup selenium-webdriver chrome proxy

```
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
let opt = new chrome.Options().addArguments('--proxy-server=http://xxx%5Cusername:PASSWORD@proxyserver:port');

const driver = new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").setChromeOptions(opt).build();
await driver.get("https://google.com/");
```

The username and password does not seem to be passing into the proxy.

Any idea where I'm going wrong

Comment: Nobody has the answer, you should configure your proxy provider with IP Authentication instead of username/password authentication. The problem will come if your app runs with dynamic IP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888323/how-to-override-basic-authentication-in-selenium2-with-java-using-chrome-driver
Referring to this question