# Send Username and Password using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to scrape a local website using selenium and need to send Username and Password to be logged in but there is no inspect element to find these elements. The website is like this:
[image]

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434362/how-can-i-send-user-name-and-password-in-popup-using-selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send keys to popup using Selenium, you can first switch your target to the popup

`obj = driver.switch_to.alert`

Then send keys using

```
obj.send_keys(username)
obj.send_keys(str(Keys.TAB)) # send a tab to go to the next field
obj.send_keys(password)
```

Reference: [Handle alert popup inselenium](https://www.techbeamers.com/handle-alert-popup-selenium-python/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try this URL format in `driver.get()`:

```
http://username:password@the-site.com
```