# Authentication Required popup in Firefox in Selenium when register

Tags: authentication, https, selenium, popup

I have a selenium2 test by junit4,FireFox3.5, when type some register information then click an button to submit,it will turns to HTTPS Authentication Required popup. How can I handle this security popup input username and password. then it will turn to an https page and register succeed.
[Image like that](http://www.lib.stu.edu.tw/images/firefox_authentication_dialog_for_RPA.png)

```
public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
selenium.open("/");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
selenium.select("year", "label=2014");
selenium.select("day", "label=03");
selenium.type("firstName", "asd");
selenium.type("lastName", "df");
selenium.click("//div[@id='page-body']/div[1]/input");
Thread.sleep(30000);
```

Comment: [Firefox Authentication popup -Resolved using Sikuli script in Windows/Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22628748/3458698)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can make you use of the AutoIT script to handle this popup.

**AutoIT script**

```
WinWaitActive("Authentication Required")

Send("username")

Send("{TAB}")

Send("password")

Send("{ENTER}")
```

Through this script I hope you will able to handle.