# Handling Browser Authentication using Selenium

Tags: authentication, selenium, browser, automation

Does anyone know about handling Browser Authentication using Selenium or any other tool during automation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium Webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: The relative dates of the questions is one factor but not the most important one. The relative quality of the two set of question and related answers is much more important. The accepted answer here starts with "this is outdated , go see that other answer". You can do a search on SO's Meta for "[duplicate-questions] newer" to read the various posts that cover this topic. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers) question in particular.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### EDIT in 2015:

This answer is outdated. WebDriver nowadays supports authentication! See [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver)

---

### Original answer:

This is not handled very well by Selenium.

---

You can try using `http://username:password@example.com/yourpage`

instead of just `http://example.com/yourpage`

However, as far as I know, Firefox will still pop up a browser dialog requesting a confirmation.

---

You can try [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) if you're using Java (or any similar tool like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/)).

---

You could use [`driver.manage().addCookie()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html#addCookie%28org.openqa.selenium.Cookie%29) if you're using WebDriver.

---

Or a custom [FirefoxProfile](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html#FirefoxDriver%28org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile%29) that has already passed the authentication once.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which path did you take in the end, what was your solution?

Comment: You can try using http://username:password@example.com/yourpage

instead of just http://example.com/yourpage

Comment: This posting contains some very relevant information to bypass NTLM browser authentication using Selenium: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021602/http-basic-auth-via-url-in-firefox-does-not-work

Comment: What will solution 3 do? the one with cookies?

Comment: @Timur Sorry, this answer is old, WebDriver nowadays supports authentication! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Yes. See that's what's used in the link I put into my last comment,.

Comment: I successfully used the FirefoxProfile mentioned above. See https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/using-selenium-webdriver-with-windows-authentication for an example.

Answer (score 7):

I spent days on this - literally.
Trying to get past browser level authentication within my company network to hit an application.
The solution was to use the 'unsername:password@' component within the URL, **BUT to add a forward slash at the end of the login URL**.

So total login URL looks like this (note the '/' after *yourpage*):

*http://username:password@example.com/yourpage/*

Works with Watir, Capybara and Selenium Webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

All the hacks via auto-it, sikuli, etc. just wasting your time when you'll run it in your CI solution, using several browser types / OS / Version / Resolutions etc.

The way to do it correctly is to identify the authentication actual method and perform a login using Rest protocol for instance.

I used it to get the JSESIONID cookie and insert it to the selenium driver.
hint on that: go to a non-exiting url of the domian first, then set the cookie, then go to the required url - you are logged-in.

use: rest client authentication to get the JSESSION ID

and With this information:

```
browser().navigate(foo.getUrl()+"non-exiting-url");

//the information got from the rest client login:
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value, domain, path, expiry, isSecure, isHttpOnly);

try {
    driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}

browser().navigate(foo.getUrl());
```

Comment: Can you describe what a 'non-exiting-url' is?

Comment: for ADFS login and redirect in Jenkins pipeline, this can work.

Answer (score 1):

Everything I have read on the Web didn't help me. So before making a request, like this:

```
driver.get(url);
```

you have to run a new thread like this:

```
RunScript runScript = new RunScript();
runScript.start();
```

In this case you are free to input login and password on another thread of follwing class

```
public class RunScript extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        File file = new File("D:\\jacob-1.18-x86.dll");
        System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());
        AutoItX autoIt = new AutoItX();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        autoIt.winActivate("yourWindowName", "");
        autoIt.winWaitActive("yourWindowName");
        if (autoIt.winExists("yourWindowName")) {
            autoIt.send("username{TAB}", false);
            autoIt.send("password{Enter}", false);
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        //
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use auto IT script to handle this problem

```
WinWaitActive("[CLASS:Chrome_WidgetWin_1]", "", time)
Send("user")
Send("{TAB}")
Send("pass")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 0):

with Chrome 70 and other versions :

```
http://username:password@example.com/yourpage
```

Comment: agree, but as firefox context was explicit, thought worth rescoping too...

Answer (score -1):

You can use Java Robot class with Selenium 2 /Selenium WebDriver using Firefox

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://localhost:9990");

    WebElement myDynamicElement = driver.findElement(By.id("app"));

    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();


    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        alert.sendKeys("username");

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);//go to password feild

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);


        } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Using Selenium with Robot
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html