# Selenium Basic Authentication Tomcat - Solution for Chrome, IE, Firefox

Tags: selenium, cross-browser, basic-authentication, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am using Selenium WebDriver with Java. So I have a website A from which after I fill form I go to website B but before it asks a Basic Authentication Username and Password.

I read in SO that, Basic Authentication Support Is not provided in Selenium.

I read somewhere I can use ROBOT Class(not sure what do u mean by that in Java) but it is risky to use.

I am not sure how to handle this event as after I reach to B I have to do some more validations before Passing the test case.

I hope someone can help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to overcome it by using the following URL

```
http://username:password@www.example.com/
```

Don't forget to give a `/` at the end. I think you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395462/handling-browser-authentication-using-selenium)

Comment: Thank your your comment, but the problem was solved using autoIT a windows scripting tool.