# Proxy issue with running tests

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy

Some how the driver clicks the site information button.

I am using sendkeys to enter this the proxy but when the site infromation tooltip open it disrupts the proxy send keys.

How would I simulate a click in the middle of the screen to make sure the site information tooltip isn't displayed?

[image: problem]

Comment: Did you look this link ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10397032

Comment: Doesn't work, it nots finding the alert that way