# How to simulate TAB key pressing with IE driver server

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

Regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671662/how-to-handle-windows-authentication-popup-in-selenium-using-pythonplus-java) issue, I'd like to send `username`/`password` to alert input fields using `IE`, but password field is always empty- all text goes to username field

Code and output:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

username = "some_user"
password = "some_pass"

driver.switch_to.alert.send_keys(username + Keys.TAB + password)
# text in username field: "some_user.some_pass"

driver.switch_to.alert.send_keys(username + '\t' + password)
# text in username field: "some_user    some_pass"

driver.switch_to.alert.send_keys(username + u'u\0009' + password)
# text in username field: "some_user    some_pass"
```

So how to put cursor to "password" field after sending keys to "username" field

Comment: I think there is bug in IE driver because of which its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who faced same issue here is solution for **Windows**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import ahk

driver=webdriver.Ie()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.engprod-charter.net/')
ahk.start()
ahk.ready()
ahk.execute('Send %s ' % username)
ahk.execute('Send %A_Tab%')
ahk.execute('Send %s ' % password)
driver.quit()
```

[`AutoHotKey`](http://ahkscript.org/) is the automation tool for `Windows` which [accessible via Python](https://pyahk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)