# How to handle Windows Security pop up in Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0[Windows 10] using katalon studio?

Tags: groovy, automation, microsoft-edge, basic-authentication, katalon-studio

I want execute my script on edge browser for basic authentication 
I have tried with below approach but it does not work

1)String URL = "http://" +Username + ":" + Password + "@" + URL
WebUI.navigateToUrl(URL)

2)I have also try with robot class

OS: Windows 10
I am using katalon Studio

If any one know how to hanldle Windows Security pop up in Microsoft Edge **44.18362.449.0**

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Please post your code, HTML of the page in question and any error messages you are getting.

Comment: Which king of script format are you using,Selenium format or Katalon Studio's standard format?Can you share the related code to reproduce the problem? Besides,can you capture a screenshot about the windows security popup, do you mean the windows security warning?If that is the case,I suppose we can't close it through selenium. Here are some related articles, you could refer to them: [Handle Pop Up Dialog Box in Katalon STudio](https://www.toolsqa.com/katalon-studio/handle-pop-up-dialog-box-in-katalon-studio/), [handle windows authentication popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671662/)