# How to Handle "Authentication Required" Pop-up in selenium

Tags: selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to handle "Authentication Required" Pop-up in selenium which having fields as "UserName" and "Password" using Alert.

[image]

Comment: If the authentication pop-up is from HTTP Basic Auth you can send the username and password in the URL: `http://username:password@example.com/`; see also http://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters/371918

Comment: Sure but in which programming language?

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ I want to handle “Authentication Required” Pop-up in selenium using java programming language.

Comment: Check out this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395462/handling-browser-authentication-using-selenium/10397032#10397032

Answer (score 0):

You can check for alert popup.
for this you need to import following,

```
import org.openqa.selenium.security.UserAndPassword;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

First you need to wait until that pop up is coming.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
```

Then check for alert popup is present/visible or not

```
Alert alertPopUp = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

Then you can use authenticateUsing method of selenium web driver.

```
alertPopUp.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("your_username", "your_password"));
```

There is also anoother way to to quick check,
If you want to just verify present of alert

```
try {
  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
  alert.accept();

 } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
   // Alert not available
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Method 'authenticateUsing' does not exist!!

Comment: "authenticateUsing" has been removed since Selenium 3. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6890

Comment: I am having no luck using Safari

Answer (score 0):

I got this working in IE using the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Ie()
driver.get("https://scdm.corp.vha.com")
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.authenticate("username","password")
time.sleep(20)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across this issue while testing the [The-Internet](http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/) Basic authentication Pop-Up. The solution is

`driver.get('http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth')`

Add the username and password in the URL itself. I tried it in chrome and firefox both are working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using AutoIt for Authentication popup you can just do this

```
driver.get(http://Username:Password@SiteURL)
```

Comment: This is depricated. Do not use this.

Comment: It's working for me. Anyway, what you are suggesting to use instead of this?