# Chrome webdriver is not sending keys to pop up

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]I am using the below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import os
import win32com.client as win32

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://itsm.windstream.com/')

shell = win32.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")

time.sleep(5)
shell.Sendkeys('My_id')
shell.Sendkeys('{TAB}')
shell.Sendkeys('My_password')
shell.Sendkeys('{ENTER}')
```

Once i open the link, Chrome will pop up asking the id and password.
I am using shell and it was working previously.
Now this is not working.

Getting console output as (chrome Console)

```
text.cc Not Implemented
```

[image]
In python shell, No errors shows up.
Please assist.
Thanks.

I tried everything available in stack over flow and it doenst work

Comment: to what you're trying to send keys? any id or something>?

Comment: Its the authenication pop up in chrome

Comment: The sign in pop Up which asks for user name and password to enter into the site.

Comment: You can check with the link, in the code i provided.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Browser Authentication using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395462/handling-browser-authentication-using-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding a new line.

```
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to_window(window_before)
```

Even though the driver is in the current frame, the new update of chrome driver doesn't recognize. After switching to current window, the code works.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If it's kind of alert type, you can use Alert objects

```
alert = driver.switchTo().alert()
alert = wait.until(alertIsPresent())
```

and then

```
alert.getText()
alert.sendKeys()
aler.accept()
alert.dismiss()
```

Comment: @MadanRaj
Can you please attach the screen? 
Can you check in chrome dev_tools id/class of the pop-up?

Comment: Added the screenshot now in my question.

Comment: @MadanRaj Alert, prompt etc are accessible via alert object in selenium. You can send keys with username then "Tab" then password and alert.accept()

Comment: NoAlertPresentException:

Comment: @MadanRaj
What type of initialization you are using?
Are you waiting for it?
alert = wait.until(alertIsPresent())

Comment: I used time.sleep(20).. Checked .. the alert is present.. and recieving the error.. No alert present.

Comment: @MadanRaj Please, check here. Probably we are missing something.
http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-handle-javascript-alerts-confirmation-prompts

Comment: I cannot switch to alert as it says there is no alert.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass authentication while you `get` the url, something like this

```
driver.get('http://admin:admin@itsm.windstream.com');
```

Comment: In the chrome driver console , reciecving such as text.cc (1763) Not implemented

Comment: It doesnt seems to be error but the keys are not going to the sign in place.