# I have got a sign up alert on my web. How can I handle it

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I got an authentication pop-up which asks for name and password in order to access the website. How can I handle this?[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Browser Authentication using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395462/handling-browser-authentication-using-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basic authentication pop-up and you can bypass it just by passing url like this `https://username:pwd@dev.cudlynest.com`

Comment: it says this site can't be reached...
Server IP address not found