# Zscaler authentication with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, authentication, zscaler

I'm having issues getting started with using Selenium. When attempting to navigate to a website, I have to use my company login to be authenticated.
[image: Authentication Window]

This code is my attempt at automatically authenticating. It results in a 404 error page.

```
string url = @"http://DOMAIN\USERNAME:PASSWORD@webpagetest.org";
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "http://webpagetest.org");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions
{
    Profile = profile
};
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

Comment: I've just hit the same problem, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Ralph Unfortunately no, my solution was to use internet explorer which allowed me to skip it. This worked for me but I believe it is just specific to my work environment.

Comment: Does it is related to this thread?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395462/handling-browser-authentication-using-selenium