# Pop-up window need to give password

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-firefoxdriver

When i open website there pop-up window asking password(admin) and without user name so how handle the pop-up authentication window by using selenium java and I was used Firefox driver.

My requirement is without user name and only enter the password as admin type need to handle the pop-up window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Browser Authentication using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395462/handling-browser-authentication-using-selenium)

Answer (score 1):

If your application is protected by [basic access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) you should be able to bypass it by simply providing your credentials as a part of the URL string:

```
driver.get("http://your-username:your-password@example.com");
```

More information:

- [How to send Basic Authentication headers in Selenium?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12892/how-to-send-basic-authentication-headers-in-selenium)
- [Authentication with Selenium](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Authentication+with+Selenium)

For more complex authentication schemes like [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) or [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) you will need to construct proper [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header and add it to your request via i.e. [BrowserMob](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) Proxy. Check out [Handling Authentication Requests with Selenium - Prologue](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2019/05/handling-authentication-requests-with.html) article for more information on implementing this if needed.