# Selenium Firefox Webdriver LogIn in company Sharepoint with Python struggle

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sharepoint

i'm trying to log into our company sharepoint with webdriver firefox, i manage to get in at the first request of username and password, then this pop up appears under the browser tab when i try to access EDMS.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkY8e.jpg)

I've tried the following:

-Locating it with Xpath locator-->Xpath locator seems to not be able to find anything at all on this page, like the page was not existing
-Inspect the websource-->pagina is empty, no code, no class or name i can use to find the elements
-Switch to alarm/swith to frame with webdriver-->doesn't work
-Give in directly my username and password together with driver.get(username:password,www.site.com), also nothing.

I get this error in PyCharm:

"Message: Dismissed user prompt dialog: http://hqeispwfep01 vraagt om uw gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord."

Note:("vraagt om uw gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord" this means "ask your username and password" in dutch)

I literally browsed any source of information i could in the last two days and couldn't find a solution.

Thanks for your help.

Br
Paolo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling Browser Authentication using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395462/handling-browser-authentication-using-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

The popup isn't part of the website.

It's browser authentication and you need to solve it by using the password and username when sending the request for the website, as described here: [Handling Browser Authentication using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395462/handling-browser-authentication-using-selenium)

Comment: Cornelius, thanks for your answer. I've already tried that and it doesn't work, the browser authentication window keep loading and i don't see my username and password be filled in by selenium.

Comment: Also, my username is an email adress and it contains the character "@", can this be in conflict with the @ that has be put between the password and the website adress?