How to Negotiate a Kerberos/NTLM Token in Java?
I'm trying to implement an HTTP proxy in Java that adds Windows Integrated Authentication to all requests.
What I have in mind is basically to negotiate the correct authentication scheme between the proxy (in the domain) and the server which, as I understand it, should result in some kind of token that can simply be added to the requests in the Authorization header.
The background here is that we're trying to use a Selenium Grid with agents outside of the domain. So negotiating the authentication directly in the browser doesn't work.
We already have a BrowserMobProxy in place to handle Basic Authentication, however we also need WIA.
Does anyone have an idea how I can generate that required token? Or maybe I've got it wrong and this approach doesn't work at all for some reason?
Any help would be appreciated!

not sure you'd be able to do that outside of the domain... but this is a "negotiate" call: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4559.txt It's handled by the browser and will only be done if the site is in the "local intranet" and/or "trusted" zone. You might need the master key for the domain and/or access to the keyring to generate these certs/tokens.  It would be extremely insecure to pass around those kinds of private keys.

The proxy can be part of the domain. I've updated my post to reflect that.

Usually you'd join a computer to a domain, not a proxy.  So the server running the proxy must be a part of the domain.  On Windows it'll be using some DPAPI under the hood.  That ties encryption to do the machine and/or login.  The only way around that would be if you had master keys/key ring. (and plugin in browser?)  The browser should also be on the machine that is a member of the domain.  You'll want to manually create a profile, go to the site protected by windows auth, enter credentials if needed.  Close the browser and use the same profile for webdriver session.

@browsermator: That's half nonsense. Authentication is not encryption (even if it happens to be encryption-based under the hood) and there is no "master key for the domain" that would be needed – the client only needs to know its own Kerberos key (which it directly derives from its password), everything else is handled by the protocol. At most places it doesn't even need domain membership for the client (requirement for FAST armoring is more of an exception than the rule).

You're probably right... I'm just imaging how you would transfer the hash over from a windows machine where it's protected by DPAPI and domain.  Needless to say it's difficult to circumvent DPAPI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms995355(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

@browsermator: It's very easy to circumvent DPAPI when DPAPI is not being used in the first place. Kerberos authentication doesn't use DPAPI in any way. More to the point, you don't need to extract or transfer any hash from Windows – the user's password itself is what produces the key (i.e. there is nothing like "password decrypts the key" here, hence no need for DPAPI), so as long as you know the password you can use any Kerberos client software to talk to the KDC and get tickets.

if all that is needed is username and password, you should be able to manually create a new profile, manually log that in... close the browser.  Then set Selenium to use that profile when it launches the driver.  If this doesn't work, you'd need to use a robot-like framework to enter the username/password manually.  (There used to be a way to put username/password in URL, but I don't think that works anymore.)  See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395462/handling-browser-authentication-using-selenium

You may also want to check the new Bidi protocol for onAuthRequired: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/webdriver_bidi/network/

I'd ignore NTLM if possible; everyone is trying to get rid of it, not to have more of it.
Java seems to have built-in Kerberos support as part of JAAS, which can either use its internal implementation (which needs credentials to be provided e.g. as a keytab) or integrate with Windows native SSPI (which can automatically use the service's AD credentials). In theory, as long as SSPI is used, it could do Kerberos and NTLM. There is another implementation, Apache Kerby, but it seems to be much more barebones.
Note that HTTP Negotiate uses SPNEGO – that's two layers of wrapping around an actual raw Kerberos token (AP-REQ), just to avoid confusion when reading docs and trying to send the wrong kind of "Kerberos token". The standard interface around Kerberos is GSS API (which produces its own tokens that basically just carry a Kerberos token inside), and Java can do that natively – but many Windows protocols use SPNEGO which is another intermediate layer (that's the one that multiplexes Kerberos and NTLM), and most web servers will specifically want GSS<SPNEGO<Kerberos>> tokens instead of plain GSS<Kerberos> tokens.
I haven't dealt with Java to this extent, but kerb4j looks like what you need to handle everything on your behalf (acquiring Kerberos tickets via Apache Kerby, generating GSS-SPNEGO tokens, etc).

Thank you for the very detailed response. kerb4j seems to be exactly what I need.
