# Authentication with selenium (Python)

Tags: selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have the links to the admin area of my website: it is possible to launch those URIs (links) with selenium (in a given browser) without needing to authenticate previously ? If not, then how could I deal with authentication using selenium ?

Comment: Selenium doesn't deal with authentication too well.  This might be useful for some alternative workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021602/http-basic-auth-via-url-in-firefox-does-not-work

Comment: What sort of authentication?

Comment: why to downvote ? :) It is resolved 4 months ago :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you mean but you can just use selectors and enter credentials to the authentication fields. i.e.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id("IDOFLOGIN").sendKeys("YOUR LOGIN")
driver.find_element_by_id("PASSOFLOGIN").sendKeys("YOUR PASSWORD")
driver.find_element_by_id("login button").click()
# Continue
```

you can find element not necessarily by ID you can also you class, xpath and so on.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.  In my case, though, I needed to add `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` after the first line and then change `sendKeys` to `send_keys`