# Chromedriver basic authentication alert pop up not detected

Tags: webdriver, basic-authentication, selenium-chromedriver

I am having issues detecting Basic Auth alert with ChromeDriver 2.14 (Chrome 40.0.2214.111 (64-bit));
I am instantiating the driver like this:

`new ChromeDriver(DesiredCapabilities.chrome());`

and then navigate and wait for pop up:

```
    driver.navigate().to(URL);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("test", "test"));
```

But it times out after 10 seconds with the error message `no alert open`. I can see that there is an alert open for basic auth.

Can you see anything wrong with the code or is it a bug with the driver?

I have seen some old question relating to a chromedriver bug. I haven't seen any other question relevant.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is similar to this question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543989/how-to-close-authentication-pop-up-in-selenium-ie-webdriver/28544422#28544422)

`Authentication popup` is NOT generated by Javascript / it is not a javascript alert. So It can not be handled by WebDriver. So the above behavior is expected.

Below `authenticateUsing` a beta method is not yet implemented.

```
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("test", "test"));
```

Comment: @gdiamantidis, you have got a company - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878208/webdriver-http-authentication-dialog

Comment: good to know I am not alone :). I'll follow those suggestions. thanks

Comment: Downvoters, do you know a better answer for this? if yes, please provide