# Multiple Authentication with Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver to access a website.
driver.get("http://user:password@samplewebsite");

Two authentications are required for accessing the site.
First authentication works since I have given user:password@samplewebsite

But the second authentication popup is for another site.
eg: https://samplesite2

How to handle this multiple authentication problem.

Could someone let me know whether there is any solution for such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with alert.authenticateUsing() method in Alert. I hope it may help you.

You may see the link below too:

[Webdriver - HTTP authentication dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878208/webdriver-http-authentication-dialog)

Comment: Which one should I use. There are many suggestions and there is no accepted answer.

Comment: I got the solution. I have posted it. Thanks @optimist_creeper

Answer (score 0):

For my solution, if there are two authentications.

Authenticate the second one first.

```
driver.get("http://user:password@samplewebsite2");
```

Then call the required url.

```
driver.get("http://user:password@samplewebsite1");
```