# What can developers do to make the browser ui easy to automate for testing?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, browser-automation

I'm curious what things a developer can do to make the creation of automated tests easier for testers using selenium web driver. The only thing I'm thinking of is using unique IDs for fields, buttons, etc. Can anyone think of any thing else that can be done?

Comment: This question is not a good fit for SO and will likely be closed soon. This would be better asked on sqa.stackoverlfow.com. SO is for answering specific programming questions.

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, this really helps to automate whole process:

- Provide unique IDs to at least important buttons (submit form, search buttons...)
- Do not use [HTTP Basic Authentification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27878208/855636). Use normal login instead
- Get rid of CAPTCHA fields. At least on test environment.
- Provide friendly URLs, so that certain areas of app can be reached immediately
- When page is loading, show some load image. Best option is to provide some small element which loads only when whole page is loaded.
- Get rid of hover-only menus on page (you have to hover certain element to see other)